# GroovyWS JAXB Bindings

Tags: grails, soap, groovy, jaxb, groovyws

Using GroovyWS the usual way to consume SOAP service.
following error: JAXB - Property “Value” is already defined. Use  to resolve this conflict

Question is, How can I change JAXB Bindings when I use GroovyWS

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally just used wslite library